# How do I check if any single element from an array is in a string?

Tags: php, arrays, find

I'm trying to create a function that searches through the user input to see if they have
entered the name of a day.  For some reason, this function only seems to return true if any two day names have been entered.  This could be something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['query']))
{
    $query=$_POST['query'];
    $dow=array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday',
        'friday','saturday','sunday');

    foreach($dow as $day)
    {
        if(stripos($query, $day)==FALSE)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            echo"hurray";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <form action="datefunctiontester.php" method="post">
        <p>Search</p><input type="text" name="query">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: try this `if(stripos($query, $day)===FALSE){`. Not I am using 3 '=' and not 2.

Comment: Why would the current function return true if two entries are entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
if (stripos($query, $day) === FALSE){
```

and not

```
if (stripos($query, $day)==FALSE){
```

This is because, if the name is found in the starting of the query, it will return '0' because the position of first character will be 0 which is false. To check if it exists use `===` which checks the type and not the value.

Also, you can use the [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function instead of for loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['query']))
{
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $dow = array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday');
    if (in_array($query, $dow) 
    {
        echo"hurray";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

=== not == see the [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) manual entry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['query']) {
   $dow = array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday');    
   if (in_array(trim(strtolower($_POST['query'])), $dow) echo"hurray";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `stripos()` in this case.

```
// Force lower case for comparisons
$query = strtolower( $_POST['query'] );
$dow = array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday',
    'friday','saturday','sunday');

$found = in_array($query, $dow, true);

if($found)
{
    // do something
}
```